# How to see which applications use "Host process for windows services" to eat metered data?

Tags: windows-8.1, firewall, services, bandwidth, glasswire

I have to spend a lot of time on metered connections in a country where data is expensive. I use [Glasswire firewall](https://www.glasswire.com/) to keep an eye on what software is using my precious data and to throttle programs that are using too much (or, shouldn't be using any). It allows me to see which software is using how much data, and then turn on and off internet access for the data hogs that don't respect my "metered network" setting ([e.g. Dropbox](https://superuser.com/questions/991547/stop-dropbox-for-windows-desktop-syncing-when-on-metered-wireless-connection)).

My problem is, sometimes software sneaks round the back of Glasswire by piggybacking on `Host Process for Windows Services`. The data usage shows up as being by `Host Process for Windows Services` with no clue as to which application is using the host process:

[image]

My only options are shut off Host Process completely, or allow the rogue application to eat my data unchecked - and it's depended on by many programs. For example, if I shut it down, access to the Internet through my browser stops working.

Usually, it uses very little data:

[image]

...but occasionally it goes bananas and starts downloading hundreds of megabytes of data for no obvious reason. Sometimes there's a clue in the name of the web host it's accessing, but often it's something generic like akamai.

For example, recently, with no warning or explanation, Host Process for Windows Services downloaded about 250 MB, almost all of which was from akamai, a small amount was from adobe.com (but that might have been a coincidence). I had to choose between shutting off everything that depended on Host Process (which includes my browsers), or, allowing some unknown application to eat an unknown, large amount of data for no apparent reason.

---

**Is there any way I can see *what* is using Host Process for Windows Services to eat data, and selectively turn off individual uses of Host Process for Windows Services without shutting off the whole thing?**

Answers using Glasswire or existing Windows features would be best, but installing additional software is fine too if necessary.

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svchost.exe#Service_tags) this is an undocumented API. `netstat -b` displays which service a connection belongs to, so what you want is possible.

Answer (score 4):

I asked a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/121901/is-there-a-way-to-determine-which-service-in-svchost-exe-does-an-outgoing-conn) some time ago, and finally found [an answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/12278/how-to-find-memory-usage-of-individual-windows-services/21452#21452) on a Server Fault question about services memory usage. The answer is to split each plausible services from Host Process so it works for network usage too. (Even after the split, I'm not sure GlassWire distinguishes the different services but [Nirsoft CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) or [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) does it)

Peter Mortensen:

> Split each service to run in its own SVCHOST.EXE process and the service consuming the CPU cycles will be easily visible in Task Manager or Process Explorer (the space after "=" is required):
>
> `SC Config Servicename Type= own`
>
> Do this in a command line window or put it into a BAT script. Administrative privileges are required and a restart of the computer is required before it takes effect.
>
> The original state can be restored by:
>
> `SC Config Servicename Type= share`
>
> Example: to make Windows Management Instrumentation run in a separate SVCHOST.EXE:
>
> `SC Config winmgmt Type= own`
>
> This technique has no ill effects, except perhaps increasing memory consumption slightly. And apart from observing CPU usage for each service it also makes it easy to observe page faults delta, disk I/O read rate and disk I/O write rate for each service. For Process Explorer, menu View/Select Columns: tab Process Memory/Page Fault Delta, tab Process Performance/IO Delta Write Bytes, tab Process Performance/IO Delta Read Bytes, respectively.
>
> ---
>
> On most systems there is only one SVCHOST.EXE process that has a lot of services. I have used this sequence (it can be pasted directly into a command line window):
>
> ```
> rem  1. "Automatic Updates"
> SC Config wuauserv Type= own
>
> rem  2. "COM+ Event System"
> SC Config EventSystem Type= own
>
> rem  3. "Computer Browser"
> SC Config Browser Type= own
>
> rem  4. "Cryptographic Services"
> SC Config CryptSvc Type= own
>
> rem  5. "Distributed Link Tracking"
> SC Config TrkWks Type= own
>
> rem  6. "Help and Support"
> SC Config helpsvc Type= own
>
> rem  7. "Logical Disk Manager"
> SC Config dmserver Type= own
>
> rem  8. "Network Connections"
> SC Config Netman Type= own
>
> rem  9. "Network Location Awareness"
> SC Config NLA Type= own
>
> rem 10. "Remote Access Connection Manager"
> SC Config RasMan Type= own
>
> rem 11. "Secondary Logon"
> SC Config seclogon Type= own
>
> rem 12. "Server"
> SC Config lanmanserver Type= own
>
> rem 13. "Shell Hardware Detection"
> SC Config ShellHWDetection Type= own
>
> rem 14. "System Event Notification"
> SC Config SENS Type= own
>
> rem 15. "System Restore Service"
> SC Config srservice Type= own
>
> rem 16. "Task Scheduler"
> SC Config Schedule Type= own
>
> rem 17. "Telephony"
> SC Config TapiSrv Type= own
>
> rem 18. "Terminal Services"
> SC Config TermService Type= own
>
> rem 19. "Themes"
> SC Config Themes Type= own
>
> rem 20. "Windows Audio"
> SC Config AudioSrv Type= own
>
> rem 21. "Windows Firewall/Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)"
> SC Config SharedAccess Type= own
>
> rem 22. "Windows Management Instrumentation"
> SC Config winmgmt Type= own
>
> rem 23. "Wireless Configuration"
> SC Config WZCSVC Type= own
>
> rem 24. "Workstation"
> SC Config lanmanworkstation Type= own
>
> rem End.
> ```

Comment: I must have misunderstood the first step, because when I enter `SC Config Servicename Type= own` into a command prompt (as an admin user, Windows 8.1), it just returns `[SC] OpenService FAILED 1060: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.` - where should I be putting this command? **EDIT** oh, I see, `Servicename` should be an actual service name, haha, oops! So I'll go through the list at the bottom; is there any way to find the other service names on my system? I think my rogue services are non-standard (probably Adobe or Google)

Comment: In services manager (run services.msc) right click the service and select properties