# svchost.exe eating CPU: which of these services can be the cause?

Tags: windows-xp, services, windows-services, svchost

Thanks to [these awesome instructions](https://commandwindows.com/tasklist.htm) I was finally (!) able to identify the services of the svchost.exe process which eats so much of my CPU on my Windows XP Professional SP3 (Version 2002):

```
Process                   PID    Services
========================= ====== =============================================
svchost.exe                 5516 BITS, EventSystem, Nla, RasMan, SENS,        
                                 ShellHWDetection, TapiSrv, W32Time, winmgmt, 
                                 wuauserv
```

Now:

1. Which of these services can potentially be the cause of the problem?
2. Shall I now try to stop some of them?
3. If yes, which of these services can be stopped safely and which is better not to stop at all?  (Without destabilizing the system)
4. How can I manage the services? Using `services.msc`? The problem with `services.msc` is that I have localized Windows and I see all of them translated. Is there any way I can match and stop/start the corresponding service with the english names provided above?

Thanks a lot!

PS: producing the above output to find the services of the greedy svchost.exe process was tricky on my localized Windows, since the `/fi` filtering on process name didn't work (the filter commands itself are translated to czech and it's not possible to enter them on the console due to charset issues!!! Braindamaged M$!!!). This is how I did it:

1. `tasklist /v > c:\tomas\file.txt`
2. Find the PID of the proper svchost process by memory usage.
3. `tasklist /svc /fi "PID eq 5516"`

PS: this is not a duplicate of #995581 at all, it's not about data but CPU consumption, also svchost issues were so frequent that it deserves it's own specific question, which is also about specific services. That question wouldn't solve my problem at all.

Comment: Referring to your edit and my rollback: accepting an answer is enough indication the problem is solved.

Comment: Just to say this again: Windows XP reached full end of life more than four years ago. For the past four years, with two notable exceptions it has not had **any** patches created... not even critical security updates, and not even when there are known security flaws discovered (and there are many of these!) It's dangerous and irresponsible to continue using this system. Upgrading to a supported OS should be job #1.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski no no, this is something special: this issue is so long going and *no one* had the right solution, that it's worth to emphasize it's finally solved!

Comment: We appreciate your input, but as Kamil already said we do **not** label our questions as *"finally solved"* within the Super User community.  We can easily see that by the fact that there is an accepted answer.  More importantly, you really need to move to a more modern operating system than Windows XP.  Using it is simply begging for a security incident.

Comment: this is [same like in windows 7, where WindowsUpdate](https://superuser.com/a/996072/174557) causes the issue. With a lot of updates were released over the years, WU is slow to check which updates it really needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How to see which applications use "Host process for windows services" to eat metered data?](https://superuser.com/questions/995581/how-to-see-which-applications-use-host-process-for-windows-services-to-eat-met)*.

Comment: [I think we have been here before](https://serverfault.com/questions/12278/how-to-find-memory-usage-of-individual-windows-services/21452#21452).

Comment: Sorry @Peter but none of those questions/answers would actually help me to solve my problem. Let it live on its own.

Comment: Should this be migrated to http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Heinzi omg no keep this question here. Hope you were just trolling though. As far as Win XP is concerned, I appreciate your feedback guys on the security, but it's also kinda tiring to hear this over and over again whenever you ask something on Win XP - I didn't ask for this. "You shouldn't use Win XP"... i didn't ask whether I should or should not use win xp. Some people might be not aware of this so it might be good but repeating this 10x times here is kinda overkill. So please stay on topic.

Comment: @Tomas: It was a (semi-)serious suggestion, and it would actually solve the problem you just mentioned: Since retrocomputing is all about making vintage hard- and software run, you won't get any "you shouldn't use Win XP" warnings there, since no-one will (falsely) assume that you are trying to do this on a production system.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of all: Don't use Windows XP. This is an accident waiting to happen.

That said, I am nearly certain, that `wuauserv` is the culprit: Windows Update is completely broken with Windows XP, and it no longer servers any purpose. Try `net stop wuauserv` to make sure.

Comment: thanks! It seems it helped, svchost not eating cpu now! What is interesting though, that when I stopped it, the process started to serve a new service: `srservice` - system restore service. 1) Is it a coincidence or not? Doesn't look like to me. 2) What is it the service actually doing? I was not able to find what *actually* is it doing...

Comment: It is the server component of automatic windows updates (wuauctrl is the client). As that it has to create the list of updates to install. Since some bright mind chose an O(e^n) algorithm to do so, this becomes uncontrollably slow with an increasing number of updates to consider. Since it is also responsible for running the installers, it might run an SR instance if interrupted while trying (and failing) to install an update.

Comment: Thank you Eugen! And sorry for not being specific enough in my previous comment - I was actually asking about the `srservice` not `wuauserv` - if the spontaneous startup was a result of me stopping wuauserv and what is it doing. Do you know? Anyway thank for all the explanations!

Comment: The install process for many windows updates starts with creating a system resore point as to have a known-working version of the system, if the update fails. If it does fail (e.g. by `wuauserv`being killed) the system restore service will revert to this restore point, thus eliminating any unwanted  side effects of the failed install attempt.

Comment: Aha, now it's clear, thanks! So I should probably let the srservice run and do its job, right?

Comment: It shouldn't take long - just to make it clear: The SR service will do real **work** just for a short period of time, but it will continue to **exist** until reboot. In fact, I am quite sure it already existed before, but was so low down the activity scale, you just didn't see it.

Comment: Thanks! And actually no, the srservice didn't appear in the `tasklist /svc /fi "PID eq 5516"`  before, as you see in the question. It appeared there  newly after stopping wuauserv.

Comment: Anyway, it is so braindamaged to use exponential algorithm to this... So this was the problem!!! This was why I kept suffering with this process for so long! Exponential algorithm! It doesn't surprise me with Microsoft! Thanks for helping to solve the issue!

Comment: @Tomas , Really should reiterate, do not use WinXP any more. If you need it for some odd backwards compatibility, your best bet is an isolated virtual machine. I would also ensure it is not connected to the internet. WinXP has so many unpatched remote code vulnerabilities at this point, along with little to no security updates for browsers... as Eugen said, it's an accident (complete compromise) waiting to happen.

Comment: Don't just stop the service... mark it disabled, so it won't run again. Support for Windows XP was discontinued, so it's not even as if it could find a new update, and thus letting it run in the background serves not purpose.

Comment: ... that said, the evidence here from `srservice` is it was trying to install _something_, meaning this particular system wasn't finished patching yet. It may be best to let it run and slow down the system until everything is fully up to date (or at least as up to date as it's possible to get /: ). _Then_ disable it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that's not the case - it has run on my CPU for such a long time I cannot even tell you!! IF there was something to install yet it would have been installed thousand times. I am so glad I finally got rid of it!

Comment: You can still get POSready updates via Windows Update for a normal XP machine, and that still works via the service (if you updated the service itself previously and do not use broken old versions). It's a hack by itself though.

Comment: @RayKoopa as far as I'm Aware the posready updates are not going very much longer too anyways. If he wants anything out of the machine aside from leaving it completely isolated (especially the Internet) he Needs to Switch the OS to win7+ asap (or more Windows 10 as Windows 7 also is nearing ist end of updates time quite fast).

Comment: @Thomas of course. just saying that windows update "may" be used in very rare circumstances still, which he doesn't have though.