# Split Bandwidth Usage Between Ethernet & Wireless

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet, bandwidth

I live in a rural area and have two 4G devices from Verizon. My computer is running Windows 10 home 64 bit. I'm wondering if I can tell my computer to use the Ethernet connection (Connected to first 4G device) for games, and then everything else would use the wireless connection (Connected to second 4G device).

Since my bandwidth is limited, I would like to dedicate the Ethernet NIC to online gaming, and then use voice chat on the wireless connection. I'm not sure how that would be done.

Also, is there a way to disable all network activity expect for the game (Or whatever else I want to allow) in Windows 10?

UPDATE - 2017-04-17:

I tried to add a deny all inbound/outbound on the Ethernet connection, but it doesn't appear that Windows knows to route the blocked traffic to my wireless NIC. That is what I'm trying to determine - how to route specific traffic to a certain NIC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent specific application from using metered network connection](https://superuser.com/questions/505598/prevent-specific-application-from-using-metered-network-connection)

Comment: @Twisty Thanks, that answers my second question about how to use the Windows firewall to deny network traffic, but it doesn't answer my question on how to use both NICs and how to route specific traffic to each of them.

Comment: OK, I'm mobile now so it's difficult to search the site for other answers, but there are several questions that have already been asked that explain how to do this. See if you can find one that explains how to configure an application to use a specific NIC.

Answer (score -1):

After doing more research, this link has a few solutions:

[Bind application to a specific network interface](https://superuser.com/questions/1004697/bind-application-to-a-specific-network-interface)

I might try setting up a router between the endpoints and both gateways, and then applying the routing at the router level.